# Why is MySQL inserting ' \\ ' before my links?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, hyperlink

When I insert a link through a form with PHP, my database puts backslashes before the links. I use tinyMCE.

Example, this is how it looks in the database:

```
(14, 'MULTIMÃ‰DIA', 'multimdia', '<h2><strong>RISING HARMONY&nbsp;</strong></h2>\r\n<p><strong>ITT A ZENE VIL&Aacute;GA URALKODIK.</strong></p>\r\n<p><strong>KEDVENC&Eacute;T &Ouml;N IS MEGOSZTHATJA&nbsp;</strong><strong>AZ AL&Aacute;BBI C&Iacute;MEN:</strong></p>\r\n<p><strong><a href=\\"\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;mailto:personicum@gmail.com\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\&quot;\\">personicum@gmail.com</a> &nbsp;</strong></p>', '<p><iframe src=\\"\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;/www.youtube.com/embed/1ov6USLXwGA\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\&quot;\\" width=\\"\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;270\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\&quot;\\" height=\\"\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;152\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\&quot;\\" frameborder=\\"\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;0\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\&quot;\\" allowfullscreen=\\"allowfullscreen\\"></iframe>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;<iframe src=\\"\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;/www.youtube.com/embed/bnv6dPQ5f88\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\&quot;\\" width=\\"\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;263\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\&quot;\\" height=\\"\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;150\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\&quot;\\" frameborder=\\"\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;0\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\&quot;\\" allowfullscreen=\\"allowfullscreen\\"> )
```

This should be a youtube video, inserted through tinyMCE. It does the same thing to images and any kind of links. So, my question is, why do these things appear?

Here is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blog_posts_seo` (
`postID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`postTitle` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`postSlug` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`postDesc` text,
`postCont` text,
`postDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`postID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=25 ;
```

With another table it worked fine, so it means that the problem isn't with my php, but I will copy it here if it is needed. What is this problem caused by? On the website there is a 404 error instead of the video.

If I insert them manually through MySQL, then everything is fine, but if I insert it through the form it looks like this. Also, if I use the same php with another database, it works fine. It's a paradox and I am not experienced. I couldn't find the problem.

Also, locally it works fine, it shows like this:

```
<p><iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Lcu8SdcsYnY" width="425" height="350"></iframe></p>
```

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: You appear to have an encoding problem, I wouldn't be surprised if you also had an escaping problem. Read: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/), [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: Thank you, I will read into it. But I think that it has to be something else. As I said, with another table it worked fine. A table with almost the same structure, basically the older version of this one. Can the web server do this?

Comment: That's not MySQL, that's the handling of your data in PHP, I'm sure.

Comment: Would you please look at my PHP if I copy it here? Although I have no idea why it works with other tables and not this one.

Comment: `src=\\"\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;`... wow XD

Answer (score 0):

You run `addslashes()`, or other escaping functions multiple times over your input. You might have also magic quotes on. You should keep your strings in raw, and escape them only right before inserting into database. Best by using PDO's bound parameters.

Comment: My php is pretty simple, I don't use any special functions. I forgot to mention that locally it works fine. Only on the web it shows like this.

Comment: That would lead to `magic_quotes_gpc` being on on the server. Do you take that into acount? Check here how to disable it: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php